# Import CommonJS default exports as named exports / Cannot load ES module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js, commonjs

I'm making a bot with discord.js using TypeScript,  but I get the following error when trying to run the resulting JavaScript.

```
import { Client, FriendlyError, SQLiteProvider } from 'discord.js-commando';
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'FriendlyError' not found. The requested module 'discord.js-commando' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'discord.js-commando';
const { Client, FriendlyError, SQLiteProvider } = pkg;
```

After doing those modifications, I get this error:

```
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Eliqn\projects\He2\dist\commands\general\information.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of C:\Users\Eliqn\projects\He2\dist\commands\general\information.js from C:\Users\Eliqn\projects\He2\node_modules\require-all\index.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename information.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Eliqn\projects\He2\package.json.
```

`information.js`:

```
export default class Information extends Command {
    /* ... */
}
```

`information.js` is being imported with `.registerCommandsIn(join(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), 'commands'));`. So I tried both solutions: if I remove the `"type": "module"` as the message suggests, I get `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`, and if I change the extension to `.cjs`, it finally loads the file, but I don't understand why is this necessary and don't know how to output specific files as `.cjs` instead of `.js`. And despite that, the command is still not registered correctly.

If useful, this is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "ES2020",
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "ES2020"
    }
}
```

I think there should be a more straightforward way to do this, but I find modules very confusing.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Is there a reason why you use ESM in your code? You can configure TypeScript to use CommonJS modules like this:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "CommonJS", // CommonJS
        "moduleResolution": "Node",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "ES2020"
    }
}
```

That should remove the error.

Comment: This is not a valid solution. OP has set `module` to `ES2020` for a reason. Tellig TS to compile to CommonJS is not the answer.